# C# Linq CopyToDataTable based of Linq To Sql table class structure

Tags: c#, class, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, datarow

can't quite swing this copyToDataTable method.  I'm using Linq to Sql to get my data from the database, but I'm creating my table structures manually and not using DBML files as I found this to be the easiest way to switch between DataContexts manually.

What I get now is the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What I'm doing is this:

```
[TABLE(Name = "TableA")]
 class TableA
{
    [Column] public string Name;
    [Column] public string surName;
    [Column] public string concatName;
    [Column] public int ID;
}

 Table<TableA> TableA = definedDataContext.GetTable<TableA>();


IEnumerable<DataRow> que =
                    from res in TableA.AsEnumarable()
                    WHERE someListFromParameters.Contains(res.Name)
                    select res;

Datatable result = que.CopyToDataTable();
```

The error line shows up under the `WHERE` keyword, so just after the `AsEnumarable()` statement.

So, do I have to create a `DataRow` based off the `TableA` class?

Comment: `AsEnumarable` is not a function and `WHERE` is not `Where`. Show us the actual code.

Comment: @ta.speot.is,  I capsed WHERE just to illustrate the point.  This is the actual code, with Table and column names replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to implicitly cast `IEnumerable<TableA>` to `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

What you need to do is create a new [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) and add rows to it (DataRow can not exist without a DataTable).

Here's an example (untested, but you get the idea):

```
var name = new DataColumn();
name.DataType = typeof(string);
name.ColumnName = "Name";

var surName = new DataColumn();
surName.DataType = typeof(string);
surName.ColumnName = "surName";

var concatName = new DataColumn();
concatName.DataType = typeof(string);
concatName.ColumnName = "concatName";

var id = new DataColumn();
id.DataType = typeof(int);
id.ColumnName = "ID";

var table = new DataTable("TableA");
table.Columns.Add(name);
table.Columns.Add(surName);
table.Columns.Add(concatName);
table.Columns.Add(id);

foreach(var res in TableA.AsEnumerable())
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row["name"] = res.Name;
    row["surName"] = res.surName;
    row["concatName"] = res.concatName;
    row["ID"] = res.ID;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

*One final note, please have a look at your variable/property names to make them consistent.*

Comment: Thanks Andreas.  This is what I'm doing at the moment (code not shown - but solution works), I was hoping to avoid doing it as it feels like a duplication in work (defining the table structure for link and redoing it for the query).